# Proper way to logout and return to the rootViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have a logout mechanism in place in my ios app that when the user clicks a button, the user gets logged out. How do I redirect properly to the rootViewController?

Do I just do this:

```
[self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: you can do : [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```